# Redirect non-www to www with Traefik & Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

There are several solutions posted in various places online to solve my problem, thus I'm asking here to see if someone could spot my mistake.

Based on this comment [here](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/572#issuecomment-382270057), this should direct www to non-www:

```
- traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com,www.example.com
- traefik.frontend.redirect.regex=^https?://www.example.com/(.*)
- traefik.frontend.redirect.replacement=https://example.com/$${1}
```

So I just flipped the behavior to achieve my use case. See the label block below.

But it's not working. The current behavior is:

http://example.com -> https://example.com (Unexpected)

https://example.com -> https://example.com (Unexpected)

http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com (GTG)

https://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com (GTG

I want everything point to https://www.example.com

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "2"
services:

  app: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-SSR-AngularApp
    environment: 
      - PORT=5200
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
      - default
    expose:
      - "5200"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=web
      - traefik.basic.port=5200
      - traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:www.example.com,example.com
      - traefik.frontend.redirect.regex=^https?://example.com/?(.*) # I flipped these from the example to meet my use case
      - traefik.frontend.redirect.replacement=https://www.example.com$${1}
      - traefik.frontend.redirect.permanent=true
      - traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true
      - traefik.frontend.headers.SSLForceHost=true
      - traefik.frontend.headers.SSLHost=www.example.com

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

My regex looks good to me as well, [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nDUQAH/2)

Any ideas on why this configuration doesn't work as expected?

UPDATE:

These are the responses I'm getting back from these requests:

```
curl --head http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found -> This is the redirect from http to https
Location: https://example.com:443/
Date: Tue, 05 Mar 2019 14:30:29 GMT
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8


curl --head https://example.com
HTTP/2 200 -> NO REDIRECT, should be 301
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 05 Mar 2019 14:32:16 GMT
etag: W/"74c55-CIDAqU2YBPjLVCS1Hegttk4cLvI"
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-powered-by: Express
content-length: 478293
```

Here is my traefik.toml file:

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
[entryPoints.https]
address = ":443"
compress = true
[entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "www.example.com"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "me@example.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

This is the **solution** I ended up with

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      #entryPoint = "https"
      regex = "^http://example.com/(.*)"
      replacement = "https://www.example.com/$1"
[entryPoints.https]
address = ":443"
compress = true
    [entryPoints.https.redirect]
      regex = "^https://example.com/(.*)"
      replacement = "https://www.example.com/$1"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "www.example.com"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "me@example.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

Comment: @Idez, would you be able to look at my question? Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

set `traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=false` or Traefik will add a redirection rule for all `http` request to the same requests with `https` before applying your regex.

From the [Traefik docker documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/):

> `traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true`   Forces the frontend to
>   redirect to SSL if a non-SSL request is sent.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I set SSLRedirect=false, however, it's still behaving the same.

Answer (score 0):

For my solution, I ended up scrapping the approach in the `labels` block on my docker-compose file. If someone comes up with a solution for that, I'm interested. However, in the meantime I have come up with a solution that works for my simplistic case. Instead of performing the redirect on the container, I'm performing it at the entry points for Traefik in my traefik.toml config file:

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      #entryPoint = "https"
      regex = "^http://example.com/(.*)"
      replacement = "https://www.example.com/$1"
[entryPoints.https]
address = ":443"
compress = true
    [entryPoints.https.redirect]
      regex = "^https://example.com/(.*)"
      replacement = "https://www.example.com/$1"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "www.example.com"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "me@example.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```